# Disconnected due to missing mods

Tags: mods, dont-starve-together

- I have the original game.
- I went here: http://steamcommunity.com/app/322330/workshop/
  pressed subscribe on the mods, seen in the server list
- I enabled the mods from dont starve together game.
- I tried entering the game and it gave me this error

> Disconnected due to missing mods
>
> You failed to download the required
> mods from the steam workshop because one or more are not visible to
> you

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a server-side issue related to mod re-upload. This happened with, for example, "Re-trap". It was first published on the workshop, then another copy of it was re-published and the original was taken down. You no longer can subscribe to the original one, *but* the server still has the subscription and uses *that* mod.

To fix this issue you need to ask the server host to check his mods and consequently re-subscribe and re-enable them, thus he will have all mods that are currently available in the workshop and you will be able to join.
At least this is what solved this issue in my group.